# React Query invalidateQueries updating data after post

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, fetch-api, react-query

I'm working on a simple React CRUD with React Query, and I've being stuck for a while trying to update my fetched data after I post a new item with invalidateQueries but it doesn't work, being trying many things like: onSuccess, onMutate, onSettled, etc etc, and nothing seems to work, also following the React Query Documentation. Here is my code:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

const handleSubmitButtonNew = async (data) => {
    api.createAnnouncements(data);
  };

  const mutation = useMutation(handleSubmitButtonNew, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("Announcements");
    },
  });

  const { data, status, isLoading } = useQuery(
    "Announcements",
    api.getAnnouncements
  );
```

and then in a child component I call:

```
mutation.mutate({ title: title.value, content: content.value, user });
```

Can I call the ***queryClient.invalidateQueries("Announcements");*** from another component where the "Announcements" originally is fetching?

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: have u checked if your onSuccess actually triggers?

Comment: yes, I checked with a console.log ! and it reachable

Comment: I suggest you add ReactQueryDevtools to your layout. It will help you debug

Comment: this should work - can you show the behaviour in a codesandbox reproduction? Also, you're leaving out where is queryClient coming from

Comment: @TkDodo I can't reproduce in a codesandbox because the API I'm running locally, the const queryClient = useQueryClient(); is above all (in the parent component)

Comment: you can. for a reproduction, you don't actually need a running api. You can make a function that returns some hard coded json with `Promise.resolve`